# What is the starting position of cell in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have 10 columns in DataGridView.

If i click first cell,popup window's starting position should be near first cell.
If i click 2nd cell,popup window's starting position should be near 2nd cell.
If i click 3rd cell,popup window's starting position should be near 3rd cell.

how to change `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` accordingly?

Used following code in `Datagridview_CellClick`

```
sub
 mPopup.Show(datagridview.PointToScreen(New Point(e.RowIndex , e.ColumnIndex )))
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is .NET all indexes start at 0.
The value range for both e.RowIndex and e.ColumnIndex would only be 0-2.
I would imagine that your results are that your selected point ends up being in the upper left hand corner.

You'll need to calculate where the actual cell is first, then apply that value to the New Point method.

This post has a good example
[Current Selected Cell Position](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?519975-RESOLVED-Datagridview-Current-Selected-Cell-position)

According to that post, you only need to call

```
    Dim rect as Rectangle = DataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex)
    Dim left as int = rect.Left
    Dim top as int = rect.Top
```

to get the correct Point values.
then pass that back to

```
    datagridview.PointToScreen(New Point(top,left))
```

Be sure to check my syntax, its been a while since I wrote VB.

Comment: mPopup is  ToolStripDropDown..if i use GetCellDisplayRectangle ,facing this error "Value of type 'System.Drawing.Rectangle' cannot be converted to 'System.Drawing.Point'"

Comment: I'm maybe a little confused?  You should retrieve the rectangle as a rectangle (System.Drawing.Rectangle) first to retrieve the integer values of top and left?  Could you copy the code back here as you are using it?

Comment: Position of Popup now correctly displaying according to cell click position..But after each new execution,location keeps on changing..at times displayin below datagridview..sometimes middle of datagridview..leke this keeps on changing

Answer (score 0):

You need to add up all the position offsets to get the correct point.

This code shows a contextmenu at the bottom right corner of a cell that is clicked on:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Dim rect As Rectangle = DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, False)
    Dim formBorderWidth As Integer = CInt((Me.Width - Me.ClientSize.Width) / 2)
    Dim formTitlebarHeight As Integer = Me.Height - Me.ClientSize.Height - 2 * formBorderWidth
    Dim left As Integer = Me.Left + formBorderWidth + DataGridView1.Left + rect.Left + rect.Width
    Dim top As Integer = Me.Top + formTitlebarHeight + formBorderWidth + DataGridView1.Top + rect.Top + rect.Height
    Dim pt As New Point(left, top)
    ContextMenuStrip1.Show(pt)
End Sub
```

I feel there is probably an easier way to do this but this works for now.

Comment: Position of Popup now correctly displaying according to cell click position..But after each new execution,location keeps on changing..at times displayin below datagridview..sometimes middle of datagridview..leke this keeps on changing